# How to refer autogenerated Role to attach to new IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am creating a custom policy to attach it to the IAM role which has been autogenerated by AWS.

Below is the policy:-

```
  rRotationLambdaDecryptPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    DependsOn: rSecretRotationScheduleHostedRotationLambda
    Properties:
      Description: "Providing access to HostedLambda for decrypting KMS"
      ManagedPolicyName: CustomedHostedLambdaKmsUserRolePolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Sid: AllowLambdaDecryptKMS
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - kms:Decrypt
            - kms:CreateGrant
          Resource:
          - !Sub arn:aws:kms:*:${AWS::AccountId}:key/*
          Condition:
            ForAnyValue:StringLike:
              kms:ResourceAliases: alias/SecretsManager_KMSKey
      Roles: <friendly rolename>
```

In Roles parameter , as i am not fully aware of the Rolename, so have been trying to generate it from its arn.

```
      Roles: 
          - !Select [!Split ["/", !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/secret-rotat-SecretsManagerRDSPostgre-*']]
```

but once pushed to cloudformation, getting error as below:-

**The specified value for roleName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_- (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: fbd4b14e-8c0e-459f-867f-968052828620; Proxy: null)**

Not sure what is wrong here, and how can i refer it!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a wildcard `*` in the role name.

You would need to save the role name somewhere you can retrieve it (e.g. in Systems Manager Parameter store), or pass it as a parameter in to the template and then `!Ref` it.

Answer (score 0):

i looked out everywhere, and found that this will be part of next version release of SAM as it requires work to add more attributes to the HostedLambda.

Till the time i managed to retrieve it from jenkins using AWSCLI (by getting the Lambda attributes which has that autogenerated role attached) and then processing it.

```
                    aur_rolename=sh(script: """aws lambda get-function --function-name SecretsManager-research-creds-rotation-lambda --query Configuration.Role --output text""", returnStdout: true).trim().split('/')[1]
                    aur_policyarn="arn:aws:iam::${env.account}:policy/CustomedHostedLambdaKmsUserRolePolicy"
                    sh(script: """aws iam attach-role-policy --policy-arn ${aur_policyarn} --role-name ${aur_rolename}""", returnStdout: true)
```